# stacked two column charts on top of each other

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to stacked two column charts that have positive and negative values on top of each other. But with the following codes I get the column charts separate and sometimes one is hidden behind the other. I am posting the script and a sample data so that it can be replicable. I am using online Matlab

```
 retndecm(1:52,1)= [0.3715
    0.3590
    0.2862
    0.1936
    0.2177
    0.2111
    0.2019
    0.2012
    0.2162
    0.2236
    0.1874
    0.2116
    0.2569
    0.2384
    0.2436
    0.2416
    0.2590
    0.2682
    0.2695
    0.2832
    0.2616
    0.2506
    0.2548
    0.2470
    0.2612
    0.2588
    0.2399
    0.2848
    0.3023
    0.3166
    0.3535
    0.3328
    0.3187
    0.3365
    0.3313
    0.3417
    0.3411
    0.4013
    0.3717
    0.3574
    0.3288
    0.3071
    0.3271
    0.2802
    0.2787
    0.2649
    0.2619
    0.2258
    0.2432
    0.2314
    0.2151
    0.2080];

 retndecm(1:52,2)=[0.0561
    0.0462
    0.0783
    0.1246
    0.1099
    0.0921
    0.0755
    0.0675
    0.0582
    0.0599
    0.0249
    0.0137
    0.0136
    0.0108
    0.0052
    0.0176
    0.0259
    0.0183
    0.0258
    0.0312
    0.0383
    0.0421
    0.0293
    0.0376
    0.0355
    0.0344
    0.0341
    0.0321
    0.0404
    0.0289
    0.0318
    0.0374
    0.0283
    0.0289
    0.0405
    0.0321
    0.0402
    0.0528
    0.0791
    0.0756
    0.0798
    0.0892
    0.0933
    0.0978
    0.1073
    0.1194
    0.1172
    0.1117
    0.1174
    0.0960
    0.1041
    0.1178];

retndecm(1:52,3) = [-0.1152
   -0.0963
   -0.1035
   -0.1144
   -0.1309
   -0.1289
   -0.1337
   -0.1347
   -0.1272
   -0.1289
   -0.1361
   -0.1176
   -0.1057
   -0.1125
   -0.1068
   -0.1119
   -0.1142
   -0.1188
   -0.1163
   -0.1115
   -0.1098
   -0.1145
   -0.1110
   -0.1046
   -0.0953
   -0.0985
   -0.1044
   -0.0967
   -0.0964
   -0.0932
   -0.0959
   -0.0938
   -0.0930
   -0.0843
   -0.0815
   -0.0673
   -0.0609
   -0.0591
   -0.0464
   -0.0736
   -0.0681
   -0.0691
   -0.0612
   -0.0758
   -0.0658
   -0.0690
   -0.0736
   -0.0774
   -0.0731
   -0.0762
   -0.0711
   -0.0754];

ndfspi(1:52,1)= [0.6025
    0.6024
    0.6028
    0.6024
    0.6030
    0.6028
    0.6026
    0.6031
    0.6031
    0.6031
    0.6029
    0.6029
    0.6010
    0.6030
    0.6033
    0.6025
    0.6034
    0.6021
    0.6014
    0.6027
    0.6031
    0.6032
    0.6030
    0.6032
    0.6029
    0.6025
    0.6024
    0.6029
    0.6026
    0.6011
    0.6025
    0.6013
    0.6025
    0.6028
    0.5989
    0.6025
    0.6028
    0.6035
    0.6035
    0.6033
    0.6031
    0.6030
    0.6033
    0.6027
    0.6030
    0.6031
    0.6033
    0.6029
    0.6031
    0.6027
    0.6026
    0.6029];
nfundbeta = ndfspi(1:52,1)-1;


%% figures
set(groot,'DefaultFigureColormap',jet);

r=figure;
hold on;
M=retndecm(:,1)';
t = datetime(2001,1,5) + calweeks(1:52);
h = bar(t, retndecm(:,1),.99,"stacked");
set(h, 'FaceColor', 'flat');
h.CData = ndfspi(:,1)';
caxis([min(-1) max(1)]);

hold on; 
t = datetime(2001,1,5) + calweeks(1:52);
l=bar(t,retndecm(:,2),.99,"stacked");
l.FaceColor = [.5 0 .5];

hold on;
N=retndecm(:,3)';
t = datetime(2001,1,5) + calweeks(1:52);
h = bar(t, retndecm(:,3),.99,"stacked");
set(h, 'FaceColor', 'flat');
h.CData = nfundbeta(:,1)'; 
caxis([min(-1) max(1)]);

colorbar('eastoutside'); 
set(gcf, 'PaperSize', [20 10], 'PaperPosition', [0 0 20 10])
set(findall(gcf,'-property','FontSize'),'FontSize',12);
saveas(gcf,'test2', 'pdf');
hold off;
```

Comment: Please read [mcve], your code isn't runnable without `retndecm` and even still I think there' s a lot of redundant code that is necessary to reproduce your problem.

Comment: It is done, please have a look now

Comment: Try to remove every line of code that you can without the error going away. For example, if the commands to save the plot are removed do you still get the error? If you use simple bar plots with made up data, do you still het the error?

Comment: In your code you are only calling `colorbar` once and you only get one colorbar on the plot. What is the problem?

Comment: Hi, thank you, 1. the problem is I call colorbar twice, 2. I cannot use simple bar plot because each bar have different colorbar.

Comment: I see `colorbar('eastoutside'); ` once, but no other call to `colorbar` in your code.

Comment: yes, that is right I mean I have two column charts with different set, I have changed my question and description, it might be more clear now.